# Alternatives to webjar dependency in sbt-typescript plugin

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am developing a Angular-2 Play app using **sbt-typescript** plugin. all npm dependencies are managed as webjars by the sbt-typescript plugin. How can i handle npm dependencies that dont have webjars published yet?

my project has a dependency on ngx-translate/core and ngx-translate/http-loader libraries. These dependencies are not available as webjars. What is the recommended way to handle this scenario?.